# Is it possible to filter data used by pivot table based on filtering the rows in a source table in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have developed a dashboard in Excel 2007 that uses one source table in a sheet (being filled with a query on our data warehouse) and multiple pivot tables making different cross sections on this data.

I use the GETPIVOTDATA in almost a hundred formulas to give me the right value for a specific indicator in my dashboard.

This all works fine. However I now have received the question to make the dashboard for 5 different segments. As you can imagine I don't want to create 5 different workbooks for this and need to maintain the dashboard logic on all of them.

So my question is the following. Is it possible to automatically (through VBA or any other means) filter the results in my source table which is the source for my pivot tables and thus for my dashboard values.

So schematically:

DATABASE_VIEW --> SOURCE_TABLE --> 12 pivot tables --> 100 GETPIVOTDATA functions

Preferably I would like to load all the segments in the source_table (one view on my database) and then filter the data in the source table, which results in filterd source_dat for my pivots. This way I can (without requerying the db) quickly change between segments in the dashboards (refreshing pivots only).

Data in the source table has the column: CUSTOMER_SEGMENT available to filter upon.

Any help is appreciated.

Geoffrey

Comment: you can use an existing column to the filter the source data as you need, or if that column doesn't exist, you can create it and attach it to end of your source data, and change your pivot source to include that column.

Comment: Sometimes requerying the database can be snappier then multiple steps of vlookup and getpivotdata functions in your excel. However If you want to stick to the current structure you could also treat the (1 time queried) database_view in your excel as an External Datasource itself. That way you can again query it (alter your query filters through VBA or with parameter links)

Comment: Thanks guys... really helpful... after thinking it through.. I think I will dynamically set my WHERE clause in my SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate all external data connections and internal pivottables through VBA.

To make it a double learner for you I recommend using the Record Macro button and then changing a filter in your pivot table and also change your SQL query a bit.

You will now see that in the recorded macro the related properties of that Pivottable/query are stated. Filters and SQL are simply Strings in the VBA code, thus you can alter certain bits to get different filters or `"WHERE Cust_ID = " comboboxCust.Value` kind of things.

Doing it through VBA codes to change the filters and SQL is usually more speedy then having it all interactively related with the standard Excel tools (Functions, parameters, linked filters, ...)